# Elementary OS - problema con localhost, ip ambigua

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, ip

Hace poco estoy usando Elementary OS en mi notebook.

Encontré que cualquier ip que comience con << 127. >> me envía al localhost.
Ingreso 127.0.0.200 o 127.0.0.10 y lo reconoce como dirección local.

Me causa problema porque no puedo conectarme vía ssh a una máquina virtual.
En esta uso Nat y este reenvío de puertos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al conectarme de esta forma, reconoce como si fuese la misma máquina actual. El nombre de usuario de la vm es el mismo de la maquina real

[image]

Y de esta otra forma no encuentra el servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para comunicarse con máquinas virtuales de forma local, debe cambiar el tipo de conexión, debe usar Bridge (de esta forma optiene una dirección ip directamente del router) o Only Host (el cual le asigna una ip en un nuevo segmento a la VM)

Comment: @isaac gracias, funcionó